# How to add an account when Thunderbird warns "potentially vulnerable to CVE-2009-3555"?

Tags: windows-7, security, thunderbird, ssl

I just updated to Thunderbird 3.1 and now when I attempt to add in a new email account for one of my domains I get **mail.server.example potentially vulnerable to CVE-2009-3555**.

Now reading up on [it here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security:Renegotiation) I have done the given settings that are in [the config editor](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About%3aconfig) for TBird because of this error: I added my mail server to `security.ssl.renego_unrestricted_hosts` and set `security.ssl.allow_unrestricted_renego_everywhere__temporarily_available_pref` to `true` and `false`. But then the account creator basically breaks.

So how can I either A: make TBird ignore this or B: Add an account another way. I have a few other email accounts hosted from this server and they are working fine.

<sub>I understand in the end the server needs to be updated but that is currently an unrealistic option.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security:Renegotiation describes this behavior in detail. The behavior is common Firefox and Seamonkey (and possibly other products built on the same codebase).

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/710015 discusses the issue with regard to Firefox but the solutions mentioned should be applicable to Thunderbird as well.

See also http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.support.thunderbird/browse_thread/thread/69ba08af60eac3b8?pli=1 https://twitter.com/#!/kaiengert/status/47606502332178432 https://kuix.de/blog/index.php?entry=SSL/TLS-renegotiation-vulnerability-still-widely-unpatched