# Thunderbird: Error: imap.server.com : server does not support RFC 5746, see CVE-2009-3555

Tags: security, thunderbird, ssl, imap, openssl

I'm getting this error when checking my mail, and I can't download my mail. I recently updated Thundirbird yesterday, but it restarted and was working fine for many hours. I saw this question: [How to add an account when Thunderbird warns "potentially vulnerable to CVE-2009-3555"?](https://superuser.com/questions/156974/how-to-add-an-account-when-thunderbird-warns-potentially-vulnerable-to-cve-2009), which led to https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security:Renegotiation, and I checked my config editor, and the following are still at their default values:

```
security.ssl.require_safe_negotiation;false
security.ssl.treat_unsafe_negotiation_as_broken;false
security.ssl.warn_missing_rfc5746;1
```

I found the original references to these errors, but they are from 2010. It's hard to believe the server was not updated since then. http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2009-3555, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5746

I tried to open a connection from the command line, and it worked fine:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect imap.spamarrest.com:993
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Mercer Island/O=Spam Arrest LLC/CN=*.spamarrest.com
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G2
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Mercer Island/O=Spam Arrest LLC/CN=*.spamarrest.com
issuer=/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3560 bytes and written 672 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: zlib compression
Expansion: zlib compression
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: E9038FFAE57B8F588299E197E5B5698AD51E595B6E2BFEEBA0ABA899ABDC1FCF
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 3CAD63BB946E9F696BD5259472E16A4C4616B41020A30C67A5CDDBC9BE063C702A0F0A7BE83AF98EB61D1F27A8B89E67
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - e6 4e d4 d0 12 78 e6 ad-ce a5 b0 84 4d 59 ea 1d   .N...x......MY..
    0010 - fc a2 61 c2 36 e8 d5 a6-f2 3f da 74 b6 7a d7 c1   ..a.6....?.t.z..
    0020 - eb ac cf da 9a 21 02 70-da 85 38 d6 28 83 31 fe   .....!.p..8.(.1.
    0030 - e1 8d 14 ee 55 c7 02 5d-97 a3 3e cb d7 b8 70 de   ....U..]..>...p.
    0040 - 76 95 02 02 7c d8 5a 1a-f7 60 d8 fa ad f6 9f fb   v...|.Z..`......
    0050 - e1 30 92 ef 09 58 08 73-22 2c 1c bc 3c f0 a1 a5   .0...X.s",..<...
    0060 - a9 bd fb 09 52 a4 9d cd-6b a6 9c 5e 42 ab 7c b3   ....R...k..^B.|.
    0070 - 45 46 17 00 59 0a 3f b6-20 41 40 a3 2e 88 39 2c   EF..Y.?. A@...9,
    0080 - 4e 7d e6 09 ed 02 8f 3c-1e 9c 9c ce d9 88 cf 73   N}.....<.......s
    0090 - 0e d6 87 83 4a 86 30 13-22 16 9c 13 b8 17 fd ba   ....J.0.".......

    Compression: 1 (zlib compression)
    Start Time: 1434915194
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UIDPLUS CHILDREN NAMESPACE THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT THREAD=REFERENCES SORT QUOTA IDLE AUTH=CRAM-MD5 AUTH=PLAIN ACL ACL2=UNION] IMAP ready.
closed
```

So how do I work around this problem to fetch my mail? I've already notified the support of the server, but have not heard back.

Thunderbird 38.0.1
OpenSSL 1.0.2a 19 Mar 2015

---

It's happened for two consecutive updates. Is this a fault with Thunderbird or the mail server?

> Timestamp: 8/19/2015 3:54:37 PM
> Error: uncaught exception: 2147746065

> Timestamp: 8/19/2015 3:54:37 PM
> Error: mail.spamarrest.com : server does not support RFC 5746, see CVE-2009-3555

Comment: I downgraded Thunderbird to 31.7 for now and it's back to working.

Comment: The reason downgrading "fixed" the error is not because the security problem went away, see Michaels excellent answer below, but because that version was released before it was considered a critically flawed implementation. By downgrading you are exposing yourself to potential security problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RFC 5746 describes a [Transport Layer Security (TLS) Renegotiation Indication Extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5746), which is intended to protect against attackers injecting data into the connection early on and thus tricking clients and servers into communicating with each other in a manner that is vulnerable to a [man in the middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

[CVE-2009-3555](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2009-3555) is an old (late 2009) *Common Vulnerability and Exposures* identifier that basically allows you to learn more about products and product versions which are vulnerable or not to this specific attack. It's similar to a bug report ID or issue number that a vendor might assign to a problem report, except CVEs can (and in this case it certainly does) cover many different applications.

**Thunderbird is informing you** (though I agree, definitely not in a very user-friendly manner) that the server you are connecting to does not support the standard that was developed to mitigate this threat, and is aborting the connection attempt because this presents a potential security vulnerability leading to loss of privacy (specifically data confidentiality, in this case of both authentication credentials as well as email traffic).

The place where this needs to be **fixed** is on the mail server you are connecting to, so you should **urge your service provider to immediately upgrade** to software that mitigates CVE-2009-3555. Alternatively, since the problem has been known for six years and the fix has been standardized for five and a half years, I would have doubts about what other potential security issues the service provider is not taking seriously, and **personally would probably look for alternative service providers.**

If you don't care about privacy, then you can try to **mitigate** this by **turning off TLS/SSL** in your Thunderbird account settings, thus using plain-text mail transmission between your Thunderbird client and the mail server. This however leaves you potentially vulnerable to various threats, including [pervasive monitoring](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7258). Additionally, this mitigative strategy requires that your service provider's mail server allows plaintext sessions in the first place; it's becoming more and more common for service providers to configure their systems such that only encrypted connections are allowed, particularly for authenticated workflows. *Hence, this mitigative strategy may or may not be available in your specific case, and even if it is, is not a recommended approach.*

Note that ignoring this problem (by switching to plain-text email transfer) affects not just you, but also **potentially everyone that you correspond with over email.** Even if you (contrary to best current Internet engineering practice) feel that pervasive monitoring is not a threat in your situation, those you correspond with might feel differently.