# Thunderbird complains about RFC 5746

Tags: windows-8, email, thunderbird

Thunderbird complains about this error. It's happened for two consecutive updates. Is this a fault with Thunderbird or the mail server?

> Timestamp: 8/19/2015 3:54:37 PM
>   Error: uncaught exception: 2147746065
>
> Timestamp: 8/19/2015 3:54:37 PM
>   Error: mail.spamarrest.com : server does not support RFC 5746, see CVE-2009-3555

Comment: Oh, and you really, *really* shouldn't be posting duplicate questions. [You already asked this once](http://superuser.com/q/930728/53590 "Thunderbird: Error: imap.server.com : server does not support RFC 5746, see CVE-2009-3555"), two months ago.